Probability of Two Painted Corners of a Cube Lying on the Same Edge
I've been considering the solution of a certain probability problem, and I seem to be getting two different but equally likely solutions: given a cube, 2 of the corners are to be painted black, the rest white. After the painting has been done, what is the probability that both black corners lie on the same edge?
The first solution I attempted at was to consider fixing one black-painted corner and to vary the spatial placement of the second one. If we consider, then, to fix the upper-front-right corner (for example), then there are 3 possible permutations of the cube. One permutation is achieved by coloring the upper-front-left corner, the other by coloring the lower-front-left corner, and the last by coloring the lower-back-left corner. Since all other colorings are just different orientations of these three permutations (for example, if we color the two upper-back corners, we can simply turn the cube 180° so that the black corners face the front, and liken the cube to the first case), we only then need to consider these three cases. Of these cases, only the first one meets our criterion of the painted corners lying on the same edge. Hence the probability should be 1/3. Is this a valid solution? Thank you in advance.

Can you write out the two solutions you have?

In one of the solutions I fixed the orientation of the cube and calculated the probability to be 3/7. In another I didn't, hence the probability is 1/3. Are both solutions valid?

Obviously they can't both be valid! $\frac13$ is wrong, so you will have to tell us how you arrived at that if you want us to point out your mistake. (Tell us by editing your post, not in a comment.)

@TonyK ok, I just did as required

As you say, without loss of generality, just pick the upper-front-right corner as one of the two black vertices. There are now seven other vertices from which you need to choose one to be also black. Out of the seven choices, three define an edge starting from our upper-front-right corner, and the remaining four do not. That is because there are three edges starting at the upper-front-right corner.
Therefore the solution is $\frac37$ in agreement with K. Jiang's method.

EDIT:
The spirit of the wrong argument is like this:
Up to rotations of the cube, there are only three ways two black corners could be chosen:

the two black vertices span a space diagonal
the two black vertices span a face diagonal
the two black vertices span an edge

Then the probability is given by the number is desired outcomes (1) divided by the number of possible outcomes (3), so $\frac13$ (wrong!).
The reason why this is wrong is that there is a tacit assumption in problems like this that the two vertices are drawn "uniformly", as if you gave the eight vertices names, wrote all the names on eight pieces of paper, put the pieces of papers into an urn, and drew two of them without looking.
Referring back to the part I wrote in the top, once one corner is chosen as the first black one, the three situations described by the bulleted list are not equally probable. Because, out of the seven corners possible once we fixed the first black corner, only one gives the space diagonal. But three give a face diagonal, corresponding to the three faces meeting in black corner number 1. And also three give an edge, corresponding to the three edges meeting in black corner 1. So there is $\frac17$ probability for space diagonal, and $\frac37$ for a face diagonal, and finally $\frac37$ for an edge, which totals to $\frac17 + \frac37 + \frac37 = 1$ as expected.
So the error consists of grouping into cases of unequal size and then doing a count-of-desired-divided-by-count-of-possible type of reasoning on those cases.

However, wouldn't we be commiting a redundant count? By way of the method then, it seems that we have counted the case in which we color, say, the upper-front-right and lower-front-right corners, and the case in which we color the upper-front-right and upper-front-left corners seperately. But closer inspection shows us that the first case is simple the second case rotated 90° clockwise. So wouldn't we have lead an extraneous count?

@Camelot823 I am probably misunderstanding the entire question. Up to all sorts of rotations, there exists only one way to have an edge all black. All edges of a cube are equivalent. Up to rotations, there are two ways it could be a "failed" painting: (A) the two black corners span a face diagonal (diagonal on one of the square faces), and (B) the two black corners span a space diagonal (diagonal passing through the center of the cube). Is this how you get $\frac13$?

Yes, that is precisely how I get a 1/3. Is such a solution irrelevant? It seems like an accurate line of reasoning to me.

@Camelot823 I appended to my answer to try to help you see why the $\frac13$ result arises from an incorrect deduction.

You are assuming (inter alia) that the probability of opposite corners being coloured is the same as the probability of adjacent corners being coloured. This is not the case: there are four ways of choosing two opposite corners, but twelve ways of choosing two adjacent corners.

Fix the orientation of the cube. The total number of ways to select the black corners is $\binom{8}{2} = 28$. The number of selections where the corners lie on the same edge is just the number of edges, which is $12$. So, the desired probability is $\frac{12}{28} = \frac{3}{7}$.

What if I don't fix the orientation?

Here's a solution in the language of random variables and conditional probabilities.
Write $c_1,\ldots,c_8$ for the corners of the cube. Let $X,Y$ denote random variables that model which corners are painted black.
$$\mathbb P(X \text{ and } Y \text{ on the same edge}) = \sum_{i=1}^8 \mathbb P(Y \text{ connected to } c_i|X=c_i)\mathbb P(X=c_i).$$
Note that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. The conditional distribution of $Y$ given that $X=c_i$ is uniform over the set $C_{\neq i} = \{c_j:j\neq i \}$. $C_{\neq i}$ has cardinality $7$, and exactly three corners in $C_{\neq i}$ are adjacent to $c_i$, thus $\mathbb P(Y \text{ connected to } c_i|X=c_i) = \frac 37$.
Therefore $$\mathbb P(X \text{ and } Y \text{ on the same edge}) = \sum_{i=1}^8 \frac 37 \frac 18 = \frac 37.$$
